# Is there a feature to preview HTML opening tag when hovering over the closing tag?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code

Is there a way to **hover** on a closing tag and see a preview of the opening tag. For example if I hover on `</div>` I should see `<div class="card">`

```html
    ...
  ...
</div>
```

Why I want this: When you have a long file with hundreds of lines it can be difficult to know which closing tag belongs to which opening tag without scrolling up

Comment: if you click on the end tag, it should highlight the opening tag, but I don't think there is a way to show it when you hover

Comment: write an extension that implements a `HoverProvider`, when called analyze the HTML and show the start tag when hovering over a close tag

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, no. There does not currently exist builtin functionality for what you are looking for.

Note: For some languages (but unfortunately, not for HTML angle brackets or tags at the time of this writing), you can use the `Go to Bracket` command (the default keybinding for this on Windows and Linux is <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>\</kbd>), which will move to the closing bracket in a block of code enclosed by brackets, and once the caret is at the closing bracket, will toggle jumping between that closing bracket and its corresponding opening bracket.

Though you might be interested in the Sticky Scroll feature that got [added in VS Code 1.70](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_70#_editor-sticky-scroll).